# Input Action and Game Object Focus

Tags: hololens, mrtk

I'm porting my HoloLens 1 project to MRTK v2. Trying to use Input Action to do air tap. I use Select action and have mapped it to Tap gesture. It kind of works but for all objects in the scene with InputActionHandler added if I clear "In Focus Required" and for none of them if I set this flag. So how to make object to be in focus if the cursor is on it? I thought it is automatically done if user moves the cursor on an object. But looks like does not in MRTK v2. Before it was handled by HoloLens Input Module. How to address it now? I mean to get action on an object pointed by the cursor only.

Comment: can you provide your code, the error you get etc. ? See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't have issue with code per se. It's with ray casting I think. I guess it may be about MRTK gaze provider settings or perhaps issue. See more below.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out what my issue was. The MRTK has bunch of functionality included and on by default. Including spatial awareness and mapping. In my project in gets in the way. I have disabled it and all came to how it supposed to be. In HTK you have to add such staff deliberately. So I have it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the examples on input actions:

https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/mrtk_development/Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.Examples/Demos/Input/Scenes/InputActions/InputActionsExample.unity

Note that there is a bug right now (as of 2019/07/30) where the pinch won't rotate the cube in the example. However, you can say the word "rotate" to trigger the rotation on the cube

And the corresponding documentation:

https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Input/InputActions.html

Without more specific information on the version of the MRTK that you're using (i.e. RC1, RC2.1, latest mrtk_development) it can be difficult to know exactly what you're hitting, but there have been fairly significant changes even since the latest release.

Comment: I have looked at this example. My problem is that after moving to MRTK v2 RC2.1 my object looks like not getting ray cast hit for some reason. It's why I think action is not received. The object considered not in focus. I used to have cursor that have different visuals on and off object (hologram). So I could see for sure that object gets ray cast hit. Have no idea how to do the same in RC2.1. The object is flat PNG and it has mesh collider (Plane). But it behaves like invisible for ray cast.

Comment: If you have a min repro for this (i.e. specific instructions on exactly how to set it up so that people can reproduce what you're seeing?). Also, did this work on some previous version (i.e. RC1*)

Comment: The same stuff works fine with HoloToolkit 2017.4.3.0

Comment: Will try to do repro project.